# How to search on multiple fields (SQL, PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I can not search on multiple fields on php. Conditions of AND and OR are not working in three fields.

Example:

```
$string_query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM Rock WHERE author ="."'".htmlspecialchars($_POST['search'])."' AND name ="."'".htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])."' OR god="."'".htmlspecialchars($_POST['god'])."' ");
```

If you fill only the `$_POST['search']` and `$_POST['name']`, the search is successful, but if `$_POST['search']`, `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['god']` is not working. How to be?

Comment: Could you please explain the problem a little more. ?

Comment: Give an example on "not working", such as a table of data with input and result.  You are building SQL, not HTML, so don't use `htmlspecialchars`.  Use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).  (Don't use the old `mysql` extension; it is so deprecated that it is already removed from PHP.)

Answer (score 2):

hey you can use concatenate concept in your sql the following code will help you if any query you can ask

```
$var='';
$_POST['search']='adas';
$_POST['name']="ram";
$_POST['god']="shankar";
$m=2;
$n=5;
 $c=4;
if ($m==2) {
$var.= "author=htmlspecialchars($_POST[search])" ;
}
if ($n==5) {
$var.=" AND name ="."'".htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])."' " ;
}
if ($c==4) {
$var.=" OR god="."'".htmlspecialchars($_POST['god'])."' " ;
}

echo "SELECT * FROM Rock WHERE $var ";
```